# How can i get checkboxes values while transfering in second page?Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have 5 checkboex. How can I get the value of them if any of them is checked and submited into the second page.
here is my html code.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_1" value="1">y
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_2" value="2">o
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_3" value="3">t
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

here is Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
if (
theForm.CHECKBOX_1.checked == false &&
theForm.CHECKBOX_2.checked == false &&
theForm.CHECKBOX_3.checked == false) 
{
    alert ('Please make sure to check a checkboxe!');
    return false;
} else {    
    return true;
}
}


</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code before you expect any answer.

Comment: Normally, the form data is sent to the server and the server is processing it.

Comment: well try the following code, i  have no tested it, if it didn't work then let me know. also please follow AwaisQarni's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

My dear first you need to change the names of your checkboxes to any array like this

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX[]" value="1">y
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX[]" value="2">o
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX[]" value="3">t
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

On your test.php just traverse the whole array of CHECKBOX like this

```
for($_POST['CHECKBOX'] as $key=>$value)
{
  if(isset($key))
  echo('check box is checked and do some thing with '.$value);
  else
  echo('check box is not checked');
}
```

Comment: what i mean is that if no checkbox is selected then alert box should come, if checkbox is selected then i should get the value in test page maybe via php $_post[]. What you suggest does work but i don't get alert box if no check box is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
        if(theForm.CHECKBOX_1.checked == false && 
            theForm.CHECKBOX_2.checked == false &&
            theForm.CHECKBOX_3.checked == false ) 
        {
            alert ('Please make sure to check a checkboxe!');
            return false;
        } else {    
            var val=''; var arr = new Array();

            if(theForm.CHECKBOX_1.checked == true){
                val += theForm.CHECKBOX_1.value; arr.push(/*push val*/);
            }
            if(theForm.CHECKBOX_2.checked == true){
                val += theForm.CHECKBOX_2.value;
            }
            if(theForm.CHECKBOX_3.checked == true){
                val += theForm.CHECKBOX_3.value;
            }
            alert(val); //echo out array elements
        }
    }


</script>
<form action="test.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
    <input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_1" value="1"/>y
    <input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_2" value="2"/>o
    <input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_3" value="3"/>t
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

**[UPDATE]::**

```
<?php

for($_POST['CHECKBOX'] as $key=>$value)
{
  if(isset($key))
    echo "var val[".++$count."] = '".$value."'";
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i=0; i<val.length; i++)
        alert(val[i]);
</script>
```

Comment: If more than one checkbox is checked you will concatenate the the values. Also you have the value of CHECKBOX_1 for all of the values.

Comment: @experimentX - done it myself. The values will still concatenate. I CHECKBOX_1 and CHECKBOX_2 are both checked then val will be "12"

Comment: @SmirkinGherkin well, ..to display individually.. create an `var arr = new Array` and push `the values in array` and echo them out

Comment: that is cool, but if i select a checkbox then it should go to the test page in your code it doesnt.How can i get this value (1 of 2) in next page via php or javascript? could you help

Comment: it does but then i don't get alert box as that is not javascript i am trying to use JS and transfer the value to the next page. Is that possible? could you help.